# Item list is not updated when item is added in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, axios, use-effect

I have created a list of items using React, MongoDB and axios.

However, sometimes newly added item appears on the screen only when the Browser is reloaded manually (I assume the list component has to be re-rendered but I don't know how to do it).

ExpenseAmountInputContainer.tsx (**Items are added in this component**)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import InputItem from './InputItem';
import AddButton from './AddButton';
import ErrorMessage from './ErrorMessage';
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
import axios from 'axios';
interface Props {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
    setTotalExpensesAmount: (value: any) => void;
    totalExpenses: number; 
}

const ExpenseAmountInputContainer: React.FC<Props> = (
        {
            expenseAndAmountList, 
            setExpenseAndAmountList,
            setTotalExpensesAmount,
            totalExpenses,
        }: Props
    ) => {
    
    const [Expense, setExpense] = useState<string>('');
    const [Amount, setAmount] = useState<string>('');
    const [ifNotValidInputs, setIfNotValidInputs] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const AddItemToList = () => {
        if (Expense !== '' && Amount !== '' && Number(Amount) > 0) {

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', 
            {
                expenseTitle: Expense,
                expenseAmount: Amount
            });
            
            const newTotalExpense = totalExpenses + Number(Amount);
            setTotalExpensesAmount(newTotalExpense);

            axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/totalexpensesamount') 
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

            axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/totalexpensesamount', 
            {
                totalExpensesAmount: newTotalExpense
            });
            
            setExpense("");
            setAmount("");
            setIfNotValidInputs(false);
        } else {
            setIfNotValidInputs(true);
        }

        const expensesListResp = async () => {
            await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
            .then(
            response => setExpenseAndAmountList(response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : []));
        }
        expensesListResp();
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <InputItem 
                onChange={setExpense} 
                onBlur={setExpense} 
                title="Expense" 
                type="text" 
                placeholder="Item title" 
                value={Expense}           
            />
            <InputItem 
                onChange={setAmount}  
                onBlur={setAmount}  
                title="Amount" 
                type="number" 
                placeholder="Expense cost" 
                value={Amount}
            
            />
            <AddButton 
                onClick={AddItemToList} 
                content="Add expense"
            />
            { ifNotValidInputs === true ? <ErrorMessage className="error-message"/> : null }
        </div>
    );
};

export default ExpenseAmountInputContainer;
```

DynamicList.tsx (**Items are listed in this component**)

```
import React from "react";
import { List } from "@material-ui/core";
import ExpensesListItem from './ExpensesListItem';
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
  interface ListItemsArray {
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    currencySymbol: string;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

  const DynamicList: React.FC<ListItemsArray> = (
    {
      expenseAndAmountList, 
      currencySymbol,
      setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: ListItemsArray) => {

    return (
        <>
            <List>
                {expenseAndAmountList.map(item => (
                  <ExpensesListItem
                    key={item._id}
                    id={item._id}
                    expenseTitle={item.expenseTitle} 
                    expenseAmount={item.expenseAmount}
                    currencySymbol={currencySymbol}
                    item={item}
                    expenseAndAmountList={expenseAndAmountList}
                    setExpenseAndAmountList={setExpenseAndAmountList}
                  />
                ))} 
            </List>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default DynamicList;
```

ExpensesListItem.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { IconButton, ListItem, ListItemSecondaryAction, ListItemText } from "@material-ui/core";
import DeleteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Delete';
import { ExpenseAndAmountObject } from '../ExpenseAndAmountObject';
import axios from 'axios';
interface Props {
    expenseTitle: string;
    id: string;
    expenseAmount: string;
    currencySymbol: string;
    item: ExpenseAndAmountObject;
    expenseAndAmountList: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>;
    setExpenseAndAmountList: (value: Array<ExpenseAndAmountObject>) => void;
  }

const ExpensesListItem: React.FC<Props> = (
    {
        expenseTitle,
        id, 
        expenseAmount,
        currencySymbol,
        item,
        expenseAndAmountList,
        setExpenseAndAmountList
    }: Props) => {

    const DeleteListItem = () => {
        setExpenseAndAmountList(expenseAndAmountList.filter(el => el._id !== item._id));

        axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    return (
        <>
            <ListItem className="list-item">
                <ListItemText primary={expenseTitle} secondary={expenseAmount + currencySymbol} />
                <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                    <IconButton onClick={DeleteListItem} edge="end">
                        <DeleteIcon className="delete-btn" />
                    </IconButton>
                </ListItemSecondaryAction>
            </ListItem>
        </>
      );
  }
  
export default ExpensesListItem;
```

ExpenseAndAmountObject.tsx

```
export interface ExpenseAndAmountObject {
    _id: string,
    expenseTitle: string,
    expenseAmount: string,
}
```

How could I re-render the list component? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is async requests. At first I dont understand why are you deleting `totalexpensesamount`. But you should do requests in an order with async await like you did at the end.
Wait till deleting operation is done, then do post request, after it is completed, fetch new and updated objects

You should check your request and response on Network tab in Browser developer tools. You can easily understand the problem's root.
Probably you are calling a get request before your database updated

Comment: Using async await for `expenseslist` worked for me, thanks! Regarding the deletion of `totalexpensesamount`, I'm deleting it since I want to have only a single value of `totalexpensesamount` at MongoDB (and not a list of them). Maybe there is a better way to achieve it, this is my very first project using a DB

Comment: Maybe you can approach differently. Totalexpenses can be changed very quickly. I think putting this data on db is a bad idea because it depends another data. If you have backend, you can calculate this on backend side. Just store your main objects in db. If getTotalExpenses service is called, then fetch all expenses you need and calculate total expense  on BE side, then return the response